# How to handle Windows key press with SWT AWT, minimize window and go back to desktop

Tags: java, compiler-errors, swt, awt, keypress

For my firsts steps with SWT (and more generally with Java), I try to make a simple app with few basics components. It's a simple window which maximise with NO_TRIM.

Now I want to write an EventHandler on the Windows system key press to hide this window and go back to desktop. After realizing that SWT.COMMAND works only with MacOS, I've replaced :

```
import org.eclipse.swt.events.KeyAdapter
import org.eclipse.swt.events.KeyAdapter
```

with

```
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent
```

But I still get this error :

```
The method addKeyListener(KeyListener) in the type Control 
    is not applicable for the arguments (new KeyAdapter(){})
```

I can't figure out what's happening. Here's my code :

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Image;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Rectangle;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Event;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Listener;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class MyApp {

    private Shell shell;
    private Display display;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            MyApp window = new MyApp();
            window.init();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Open the window.
     */
    private void init() {
        Display display = Display.getDefault();
        createContents();
        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
        display.dispose();
    }

    /**
     * Create contents of the window.
     */
    private void createContents() {
        shell = new Shell(display, SWT.NO_TRIM);
        shell.setText("MyApp");
        shell.setMaximized(true);

        final Image tmp_img_background = new Image(display, "img/background.png");
        shell.setBackgroundImage(tmp_img_background);

        shell.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            //@Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_WINDOWS) {
                    shell.setMinimized(true);
                }
            }
        });

        shell.addListener(SWT.Resize, new Listener() {
            //@Override
            public void handleEvent(Event event) {
                Rectangle clientArea = shell.getClientArea();
                final Image img_background = new Image(display, tmp_img_background.getImageData().scaledTo(clientArea.width, clientArea.height));
                shell.setBackgroundImage(img_background);
                tmp_img_background.dispose();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

## **EDIT**

I finally found a solution to do what's was expected. Instead of SWT I now use AWT/Swing.

Here's the code I use now, it does the same thing except this time the "Windows key" bring you back to the desktop.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MyApp {

private JFrame frame;
private JPanel panel;
private JLabel label;
private ImageIcon imageIcon;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try
                {
                    MyApp window = new MyApp();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public MyApp() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame("MyApp");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        frame.setUndecorated(true);
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        Dimension frameArea = frame.getSize();
        int w = frameArea.width;
        int h = frameArea.height;

        try
        {
            panel = new JPanel();
            imageIcon = new ImageIcon(
                new ImageIcon(panel.getClass().getResource("/background.png"))
                .getImage()
                .getScaledInstance(w, h, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT)
            );
            label = new JLabel();
            label.setIcon(imageIcon);
            frame.setContentPane(label);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("File not found !");
        }

        frame.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            //@Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_WINDOWS) {
                    frame.setState(JFrame.ICONIFIED);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your compiler is complaining because you are trying to add an AWT `Listener`/`Adapter` to an SWT `Shell`. You will have to use a `org.eclipse.swt.events.KeyAdapter` instead.

**However**, from the looks of things, the Windows key is not supported by SWT.

[Here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=55236) is a bug report asking to add support for the windows key.

Comment: Thank you Baz, I've understand my mistake and finally switch to AWT/Spring for this project. And now it works like a charm, I can have my app in fullscreen without decorations (no title bar nor borders) and the "Windows key" minimize it as expected.

Comment: @Twist Please either post your code as an answer and accept it, or add the code to your question and accept my answer.